# Replace GET request by POST without form in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, post, get

So i have this JSP page which having data from table and forming a GET request to render more data on another page , by clicking one of the table line
Problem is i have to transforming it into POST method , to avoid getting information in the http request link

i know how to use post with form, but here i have to take the date from a table line and not a form
Any idea how to do that. i'm new to JSP so i don't know how to do it

```
<table border=0 bgcolor=#92ADC2 cellspacing=1 cellpadding=3 width=95% align=center>
    <tr class=entete>
        <td class=texte8 align=center>&nbsp;<spring:message code="nom"/></td>
        <td class=texte8 align=center>&nbsp;<spring:message code="date_naissance"/></td>
        <td class=texte8 align=center>&nbsp;<spring:message code="numero"/></td>

    </tr>
    <%  
            String v_Person = "";
            String v_date = "";
            String v_numero = "";
            
            for (int i = 0; i < PersonListeBean.getPerson(); i++)
            {
                Gen_rechBean cb = PersonListeBean.getPerson(i);
            
            
                    v_Person = cb.getname();
                    v_date=cb.getdate();
                    v_numero=cb.getNumero();
                    
            
                    }
                
            %>
                <tr class="<%=class_cell%>" onMouseOver="this.className='over';" onMouseOut="this.className='<%=class_cell%>';" onclick="javascript:parent['gauche'].document.location='ResultServlet?name=<%=v_Person%>&numero=<%=v_numero%>&date_naissance=<%=v_date%>">
                            <td class=texte7 align=left >&nbsp;<%=cb.getname()%></td>
                            <td class=texte7 align=left >&nbsp;<%=cb.getdate()%></td>
                            <td class=texte7 align=left >&nbsp;<%=cb.getNumero()%></td>
                    
                </tr>
            
</table>
<br>
<table width="95%" align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td align="right">
        <a target="corps" href="rechResult.jsp" class="rub2" </a>
    </td>
  </tr> 
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see what are you trying to do.

The easiest way to do that is using a form. So you can call a js method when you click the
`<tr onclick="myMethod()">`
that you want.

The method can fill your form and send the submit. Using this you can be redirected without sending data in you url.

A basic example could be:

(Supposing these are elements printed by server-side)

```
    <tr onclick="myMethod(<%=getName()%>, <%=getDate()%>, <%=getNumero()%>)">
       <td>...</td>
       <td>...</td>
       <td>...</td>
    </tr>

   <form id="myForm" action="targetFile.jsp" method="post">
      //Hidden inputs to prevent users form touching this fields
      <input type="hidden" name="name" id="data1">
      <input type="hidden" name="date" id="data2">
      <input type="hidden" name="numero" id="data3">
   </form>
<script>
function myMethod(data1, data2, data3){
   //Im gonna use jQuery. Is like javascript but quite faster to use
    //Filling the form
    $("#data1").val(data1);
    $("#data2").val(data2);
    $("#data3").val(data3);

   //Submiting it
    $("myForm").submit();

}
</script>
```

Let me know if it was helpful.

c:

Comment: Problem is, as you can see in my intial onclick event, i have to dispatch the url in two different frameset. Any idea of how to do that?